# Bypass MSW blocking file upload progress

Tags: angular, msw

I have an Angular component that uploads a file and reports the progress. When I am running mock data with msw, the request does not report the file upload progress. As soon as I turn off mock data, it works as expected.

This exact issue happens when using the Angular ngsw-worker for enabling PWA support, however this can easily be resolved by adding `?ngsw-bypass=true` as a query param, and I have that handled already like so

```
    this.uploadUrl = this.swUpdate.isEnabled
      ? this.webserviceUrl.concat('/upload?ngsw-bypass=true')
      : this.webserviceUrl.concat('/upload');
```

I already have my msw worker configured to bypass all unhandled requests using `workers.start({ onUnhandledRequest: 'bypass' });`

However, it still prevents the file upload progress from reporting.
What is the solution to whitelist or bypass a request similar to the `ngsw` way?